# Move button up to align with h2 text

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of the current solution:

[image]

**I want to move the yellow box up to align with the text. It looks lower than the text**

Here's my html:

```
<a href=""><h3>Cheetah Palm Beach
<span class="badges">TEST</span></h3></a>
```

Here's my css for the h3 title:

```
h3 {
position: absolute;
left: 353px;
top: 20px;
font: 30px/30px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
color: #404040;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0px;
}
```

and here is my css for the yellow box:

```
span.badges {
font: 14px/14px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 5px 7px 3px 7px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #e3ab15;
border-radius: 2px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 15px;
width: 165px;
text-align: center;
top: 0px;
}
```

I dont know how to solve this problem.

thanks for the help

Comment: It looks ok from your given css. https://jsfiddle.net/43mp3ojn/

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `margin-bottom`?

Comment: @Lyall yes for the span badges

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/43mp3ojn/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `vertical-align: top;` to `span.badges` if you want to align with top. And set padding `padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;` because it will make it looks like top align then text.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43mp3ojn/2/)**

Else if you want to align to bottom of the left text then just make changes in padding as above.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43mp3ojn/5/)**

Here `vertical-align` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can give you yellow box

```
position:relative; top:-5px;
```

You can see the solution here